# call a function from son class to father class in php

Tags: php, class

please check these classess:

```
class DB
{   
    protected saveINDB($name)
    {
       //insert $name to DB
    }

}

class Items extends DB
{
    private $name;

    function __construct($name) 
    {
          $this->name = $name;        
    }        
}
```

I want save $name in 'Item' to database via a method in 'DB' class.

I think I can do it like this:

```
$item = new Item('Free');
$item->saveINDB($item->name);
```

is it right?

No how can I call function automaticly in second class?

for example...when I create 'Item' object. it call saveINDB() in 'DB' class in save $name in database.(like propertise in `__construct()` method)

something like this:

```
class Items extends DB
{
    private $name;

    function __construct($name) 
    {
          $this->saveINDB($name);        
    }        
}
```

I hope you underestand me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->saveINDB($name);` will work fine in the constructor, as per your example. There's no need to use `parent::` unless you're overriding the method, because the whole point of extending a class is that the child inherits all the methods of the parent.

There is an error in your DB class though, which might be causing you issues:

`protected function saveINDB($name) // function was missing`

[Here's a working demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/Ka87Jzlk)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `parent::saveINDB($name);` ?

Comment: I think so! So how can I call it on start? I must define it on __construct() function?

Comment: Not sure I understand, just use my code instead of `$this->saveINDB($name);`